# Giving a random number to an array

Tags: c++

Good day all. I have a rather weird thing happening to my code. I am wanting to create a random number to input into my quest_postition array to use it in my grid array. I want the location to be different every time you run the program.

What it is currently doing is going into a infinite loop and displaying the grid all the way down.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

void draw_grid()
{

char grid[9][9] = { {'x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'},
                    {'x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'},
                    {'x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'},
                    {'x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'},
                    {'x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'},
                    {'x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'},
                    {'x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'},
                    {'x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'},
                    {'x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'}};
char character = '*';
char quest = 'Q';

int position[2] = {4,4};
int quest_position[2];

srand(time(NULL));

quest_position[0] = rand() % 9 + 0;
quest_position[1] = rand() % 9 + 0;

char direction;

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
        if(i == position[0] && j == position[1])
            cout << character;
        if(i = quest_position[0] && j == quest_position[1])
            cout << quest;
        else
            cout << grid[i][j];
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
    draw_grid();
}
```

Please can you help.

Thanks.

Comment: if(i = quest_position[0] && j == quest_position[1]) <- You want i == quest_position[0].
Like this, you are 're-initializing' i.

Comment: _"rand() % 9 + 0;"_ - What is the reason for `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(i = quest_position[0] && j == quest_position[1])
        cout << quest;
```

should be:

```
 if(i == quest_position[0] && j == quest_position[1])
     //^^^Error here should be logical equal
        cout << quest;
```

You may find a live demo here:[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/YHvRkd)

Meanwhile, you should use header:

```
#include <ctime>
```

and remove

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

since you have already included `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: Thanks, I did do see this (and fixed) but it gives me one to many x's in the main grid once the quest has been inserted

Comment: @Rijnhardt You may need to check the logic of your code if it does not give you expected output?

Comment: @Toacp is my if statements clashing with one another?

Comment: @Toacp thanks, sir. I corrected the second if statement to else if statement

Comment: @Rijnhardt I don't see any clash. However, you `i == position[0] ==quest_position[0]` && `j == position[1] ==== quest_position[1]`, then you will have more values output on the screen since that two if conditions may both be true. you may need if/else if instead?

Answer (score 1):

You missed == in line

```
if(i == quest_position[0] && j == quest_position[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`if(i = quest_position[1] && j == quest_position[1])`